# $A=LDU$ and also $A=L_1 D_1 U_1$. Derive $L_1^{-1} LD=D_1 U_1 U^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A=LDU$ and also $A=L_1 D_1 U_1$ with all factors invertible, then $L={L}_{1}$ and $D={D}_{1}$ and $U={U}_{1}$. "The three factors are unique."

Derive the equation $L_1^{-1} LD=D_1 U_1 U^{-1}$. Are the two sides triangular or diagonal? Deduce $L=L_1$ and $U=U_1$ (they all have diagonal $1$s). Then $D=D_1$.

This is what I have done so far:

We are given that $A=LDU$ and $A=L_1 D_1 U_1$

Thus, we can say that $LDU=L_1 D_1 U_1$

We can now multiply both sides of our equation by $L_1^{-1}$, on the left to get:

$$L_1^{-1} LDU=L_1^{-1} L_1 D_1 U_1$$

Now we multiply both sides of our equation by $U^{-1}$ on the right to get:

$$L_1^{-1} LDUU^{-1}=L_1^{-1} L_1 D_1 U_1 U^{-1}$$

We notice that on the left side of our equation, we have $U{U}^{-1}$ which is equal to $I$

We also notice that on the right side of our equation, we have $L_1^{-1} L_1$ which is equal to $I$

Thus, we have arrived at our desired result:

$$L_1^{-1} LD= D_1 U_1 U^{-1}$$

So, I have figured out the first part of the question, but I do not understand the other parts of the question, and I don't have any ideas about the answer. A hint to guide me in the right direction would be great. A direct answer will not help me.

Comment: A={ L }_{ 1 }{ D }_{ 1 }{ U }_{ 1 } ?  People actually emulate MathJax code they find here, and it makes sense that they do that.  This isn't as bad as some of the pointlessly complicated code one sometimes finds here.  If one uses curly braces where they're needed and not where they're not, the others looking at it may come to understand what the b braces are actually for. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that $L_1^{-1}$ and $L$ are both lower triangular, so that $L^{-1}LD$ is lower triangular. Similarly, $D_1U_1U^{-1}$ is upper triangular. What does that tell you?

Comment: @rogerl I can understand how $L$ and $L_1^{-1}$ are both lower triangular. $L$ is just the product of all the inverse elimination matrices required to find $U$. $L_1^{-1}$ is obviously the inverse of $L$ and is thus lower triangular as well. I don't understand why exactly $L^{-1}LD$ is lower triangular. Similarly, I don't understand why $D_1U_1U^{-1}$ is upper triangular. MIT OCW even provides the solution to this specific problem [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/assignments/MIT18_06S10_pset2_s10_soln.pdf), but my inability

Comment: to wrap my head around those two things is preventing me from understanding the solution.

Comment: The product of lower triangular is lower triangular and ditto for upper triangular.

Comment: @rogerl Ok, so $L_1^{-1}LD$ is lower triangular and $D_1U_1U^{-1}$ is upper triangular. The fact that they are equal means that they must both be diagonal. Thus, $L_1^{-1}$ and $U_1U^{-1}$ are both diagonal. We were given the fact that they have diagonal 1's which tells us that they are both equal to $I$. Therefore, we can deduce that $L=L_1$ and $U=U_1$. I Finally, we can now conclude that $D=D_1$. I hope this is right. I think I understand it all a bit better now. Feel free to consolidate your comments into an answer below. I will accept it and +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $L_1^{-1}$ and $L$ are both lower triangular. Since the product of lower triangular matrices is lower triangular, it follows that both $L_1^{-1}L$ and  $L_1^{-1}LD$ are lower triangular. Similarly, $D_1U_1U^{-1}$ is upper triangular. Since they are equal, both must be diagonal. We know that in an $LDU$-factorization $D$ has no zero diagonal entry: therefore both $L_1^{-1}L$ and $U_1U^{-1}$ must be diagonal. Since all four matrices have ones down the diagonal, both of these are $I$. Hence $D = D_1$, $L_1 =L$, and $U_1 = U$.

Comment: Adding to the explanation: The diagonals in  $L_1^{-1}$ and $U^{-1}$ have all 1's.
$L^{-1}L$ = I, L has all 1's in diagonals. $L^{-1}$ need to have 1's in its diagonal too.
If not $L^{-1}L$ will also have an entry which will have that number which is not 1 (from $L^{-1}$). Same for $U^{-1}$.